# How to stack rounded views on top of each page in view controller in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a design that I want to implement where there are three rounded views stacked on top of each other. I do not know how to implement this as when I place them in front of each other it doesn't work. I am using the storyboard and tweaking the settings of the views programmatically. How can this be achieved?

This is the design I have that is too hard to try and implement.

[image: This is the design I have that is too hard to try and implement.]

Comment: These rounded `UIView`'s are stacked upon one another.

Comment: When you say stacked do you mean that you use a stackview?

Comment: **I am using the storyboard and tweaking the settings of the views programmatically** show what you have tried

Comment: @ΒασίληςΔ. No, I am not using stackview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so I played a little with story board and I managed to recreate what you want.

The result is 
[image]

The storyboard is 
[image]

And finally the code is

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var redView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var yellowView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var blueView: UIView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0) {
            UIView.addCornerRadiusToViews(views: [self.redView, self.yellowView,self.blueView], cornerRadius: 50)
            self.redView.dropShadow(color: UIColor.black, offSet: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0))
            self.yellowView.dropShadow(color: UIColor.black, offSet: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0))
            self.blueView.dropShadow(color: UIColor.black, offSet: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0))


            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}

extension UIView {

    func dropShadow(color: UIColor, opacity: Float = 0.5, offSet: CGSize, radius: CGFloat = 50, scale: Bool = true) {
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
        layer.shadowOffset = offSet
        layer.shadowRadius = radius
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
        layer.shouldRasterize = true
        layer.rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1
    }

    static func addCornerRadiusToViews(views: [UIView], cornerRadius: CGFloat) {
        views.forEach { (view) in
            view.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
    }

}
```

You can change roundCorner values and shadow offset values to be pixel perfect.

Comment: You can use `func roundCorners(_ corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }` to make specific round corners

Comment: I am not able to implement this on my side. Is it entirely about how the constraints are set? I am using an iPhone X to prototype with and my view sizes are different, how can I achieve what you have suggested?

Comment: What version of XCode - Swift are you using? Are using SwiftUI?

Comment: You probably don't coppy correctly the constraints or you place the views in wrong order, try to create a project from scratch just to implement the hierarchy correctly and then you can reproduce it to your project.